# my jquery does not work in my material design textfield

Tags: jquery, laravel-5.6

my jquery code does not working help me please im just a student. I dont know whats wrong in my coded its work properly but jquery is not working. I have floating label textfield after I input in textfield the label back to its place and covering what i input. im not good in english

my code in jquery

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){

    $('.effect').each(function(){
      changeState($(this));
    });

    $('.effect').on('focusout', function(){
      changeState($(this));
    });

    function changeState($formControl){
      if($formControl.val().length > 0){
        $formControl.addClass('has-value');
      }
      else{
        $formControl.removeClass('has-value');
      }
    }
  });
  </script>
```

and my code in textfields

```
  <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="text" name="fname" class="effect" required autocomplete="off" maxlength="32">
            <label class="ph">First Name</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="text" name="lname" class="effect" required autocomplete="off" maxlength="32">
            <label class="ph">Last Name</label>
          </div>
        </div>
```

my css code

```
 .ph{
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: -20px;
 left: 0px;
 color: #999;
 font-family: 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
 font-size: 14px;
 z-index: 1;
 transition: all 0.3s ease;
  }
  .effect{
 display:block ;
 position: relative;
 background: none;
 border:none;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
 width:100%;
 font-family: 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
 font-size: 16px;
 color: #00aced;
 z-index: 2;
  }
  .effect:focus{
 outline: none;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #00aced;
  }
  .effect:focus + .ph{
 top:-40px;
 font-size: 11px;
 color: #00aced;
  }
  .has-value + .ph{
 top:-40px;
    font-size: 11px;
 color: #00aced;
  }
```

package.json

```
{
"private": true,
"scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.17",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.12",
    "cross-env": "^5.1",
    "jquery": "^3.2",
    "laravel-mix": "^2.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "vue": "^2.5.7"
},
"dependencies": {
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0"
}
```

}

Comment: Lol paste code don't add images

Comment: ow sorry . first time HAHA

Comment: Update with code or else you will a lot of downvotes..

Comment: i already update it . sorry

Comment: Check that you imported jquery before your custom js. Note : MDL does not have jquery as its dependency

Comment: sir for asking. but what is MDL? i checked my imported jquery i try simple custom js and its work just to know if my laravel have jquery

Comment: Material design lite [MDL]. Paste you package.json need to look at your dependencies

Comment: take a look sir . i pasted it

Comment: Try pasting the code in a new js file and then import

Comment: ty sir. im trying to do is like material design of google. thank you

Comment: its not working even if i pasted it in a new js file

Comment: Put this code in the tags `$('body').css({ 'display': 'none' });` just before this line `$('.effect').each(function(){`

Comment: its display none sir as in none.